# Can't boot from Snow Leopard DVD

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, snow-leopard, startup, build-version

I bought a new hard drive for my 2011 MacBook Pro and did the following steps:

- Backup using Time Machine
- Replaced the hard drive
- Put in a Snow Leopard DVD (10.6 from ~2009)
- Booted holding down the <kbd>c</kbd> key

I can hear the DVD spinn for a while but I never get past the Apple logo in the boot, no error message.

Why isn't it working?

Comment: How old is your MacBook Pro ?

Comment: It's the first version with Sandy Bridge, from 2011.

Comment: Perhaps the DVD is *corrupted*, or it's not the appropriated DVD (if it came with an specific computer, it will be computer model bound). Try booting holding down **Option**, and see if the DVD is listed.

Comment: @Thecafremo the DVD was listed. I think the version on the DVD is to old as Matthiue pointed out in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your MacBook Pro requires a more recent version of OS X (A least 10.6.6). [Mac OS X versions (builds) for computers on Support.Apple.com](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1159?viewlocale=fr_FR)